# How can $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$ evaluate to 2 different inverse trigonometric functions?

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I am going over a list of standard integrals to memorize and the derivative of both $\sin^{-1}(x)$ and $\cos^{-1}(x)$ only differ by a sign. Likewise with inverses of $\tan(x)$, $\cot(x)$ and $\sec(x)$, $\csc(x)$. What I don't understand is how this is accounted for during integration. Take
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

My book (NCERT Mathematics Class 12) tells me that it can evaluate to either
$$\sin^{-1}(x)+C$$
or
$$-\cos^{-1}(x)+C$$
But a desmos graph shows me that those 2 functions are not the same:

[image]

Perhaps it's something to do with the constant of integration but I can't put my finger on it and I couldn't find a note on this on Wikipedia's [list of integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_integrals).

> How do we tell which inverse trig function (of the pairs mentioned) is the correct evaluation in the integrals of their derivatives, when all that changes is a sign?

Comment: As you say, it’s the constant of integration. The two functions differ by an additive constant, so they are both correct. One is not better than the other.

Comment: They are both correct because they both have the same correct derivative.

Comment: Constant of integration is there always and implied. Similarly $\pm$ sign before sqrt sign of integral is always implied. A combination also applies like when we switch between arcsin and arccos above with $\pi/2$ and negative sign together.

Comment: Per the identity $$\sin^{-1}x + \cos^{-1}x=\frac\pi2$$
the two results differ by the constant $\frac\pi2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This all boils down to what it means for a function to have an antiderivative.  If we have a function $F(x)$ so that $F'(x) = f(x)$, then we say that $F$ is *an* antiderivative of $f$.  That said, differentiating $F(x) + C$ for any constant $C$ also yields $f(x)$, because $$\frac{d}{dx}(F(x)+C) = \frac{d}{dx}F(x) + \frac{d}{dx}C = F'(x) = f(x).$$  So, when we want to express the *general* antiderivative of $f$ we write $$\int f(x)\,dx = F(x) + C.$$  The thing to note here is that we can replace $F(x)$ with *any function whose derivative is* $f(x)$ and the statement is still true.  In your example, because
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} \sin^{-1}(x) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\cos^{-1}(x)\right) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\end{align*} then we can conclude that **both** $\sin^{-1}(x)$ and $-\cos^{-1}(x)$ are antiderivatives of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$  So, we can express this relationship as either of
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx &= \sin^{-1}(x) + C\\
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx &= -\cos^{-1}(x)+C
\end{align*}